# How to reduce app size of a react native app (expo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform

I have created a basic todo list app using expo and then built apk for it using expo cloud build service. The size of the app is ~70mb, Which i feel is too much for a basic app. What are the ways to reduce the app size. P.S - I won't be uploading to playstore , so app bundle won't work for me.

Comment: FYI: [on Expo](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-expo-is-fooling-everyone-adf7f34d7528) in case you didn't know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can only tell you to use last version of expo and to be careful with the size of images etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using some images, try to use [tinypng](https://tinypng.com/).
Also try to use **visualize-bundle**. It'll help you to understand, what takes up a lot of space for you. Maybe it will be possible to get rid of some library and replace it with another one that weighs much less or write your own solution.